# ColdFusion debugger settings

Tags: debugging, coldfusion

When I encounter an error in a ColdFusion project I am working on, I get a very generic error message:

[image]

I do not see any of the debugging output that is shown in other screenshots I have seen, such as in a reference book I have or on ColdFusion websites. What option in the ColdFusion administrator will enable verbose debugging output to help me in my development?

Answer (score 2):

1. Log in to the Cold Fusion Administrator. If you are running a Cold Fusion server on your local machine, the default URL is http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator.
2. Under "DEBUGGING & LOGGING", click on "Debug Output Settings".
3. Click on the check box next to "Enable Request Debugging Output".

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the main admin page there is a Site-wide Error Handler option. 
make sure that's empty as that stops any debugging working.

Steps to Fix

1. open CF admin Page.
2. click settings
3. scroll down to Error Handlers
4. remove site-wide Error Handler so its blank
5. click submit to safe the settings.

Comment: Can you provide the exact steps to get to that option? Please include the exact menu option to click on and the exact text of the option to disable.